# SQLite Attach command and Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, sqlite

If you open a sqlite-database from a file you can later attach another file an give it a name, in case it contains equally named tables as the first database.

Using DataContext.GetTable() will return the table of type T from the "original" database. Is there a way to get the other table as well?
How would you do something like "INSERT INTO Person SELECT * FROM Source.Person" in linq, if "Source" is the database you attached?

Comment: LINQ to SQL is designed for MS SQL only. I don't think this can actually work.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the input. Maybe I should check my SQL-based options in this case.